# Android Studio crashes after latest updates ( Aug 2019)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, kotlin, flutter

Opened up Android Studio after about 2 weeks from the last usage. Android Studio itself was up-to-date. It offered to update Android Tools and Flutter plugins. After the usual install, it offered to restart AS. And now this is what I see when I try to run my AS:

```
Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.IllegalStateException: exceptionDir.listFiles() must not be null
at wu.seal.jsontokotlin.feedback.PersistCache.readAllCachedExceptionInfo(PersistCache.kt:58)
at wu.seal.jsontokotlin.feedback.NetWorkKt$sendHistoryExceptionInfo$1.run(NetWork.kt:33)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does anyone know what is it? Thank you.

Comment: First make sure your sdk is not corrupted, You can force quit it and restart again, if not work try with restart your mac,still same issue arrive re install AS with latest dmg.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem as you after upgrading Android Studio to **3.5**. Base on the error log, I think the problem is out from [JsonToKotlinClass](https://github.com/wuseal/JsonToKotlinClass) plugin. I remove the plugin and Android Studio is back!

You can find the plugin under `~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio3.5`. Make a backup and try to remove it.

---

Comment: That's exactly what I found out too, just didn't have time to write it here. That plugin really messed up the entire Android Studio.